# Android - Out of memory Error. When it run on real device

Tags: android

I have an image gallery application, and I'm trying to get image from External Storage.My application can run on android emulator but on real device(HTC OneX) I got some exception.

My Log cat here.

```
07-25 17:17:49.027: E/dalvikvm-heap(3008): Out of memory on a 480016-byte allocation.
07-25 17:17:49.052: E/dalvikvm(3008): Out of memory: Heap Size=65571KB, Allocated=63717KB, Limit=65536KB
07-25 17:17:49.052: E/dalvikvm(3008): Extra info: Footprint=65315KB, Allowed Footprint=65571KB, Trimmed=0KB
07-25 17:17:49.052: E/MediaStore(3008): failed to allocate memory for thumbnail content://media/external/images/thumbnails/300; java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=65571KB, Allocated=63717KB)
07-25 17:17:49.142: E/dalvikvm-heap(3008): Out of memory on a 480016-byte allocation.
07-25 17:17:49.152: E/dalvikvm(3008): Out of memory: Heap Size=65571KB, Allocated=63718KB, Limit=65536KB
07-25 17:17:49.152: E/dalvikvm(3008): Extra info: Footprint=65315KB, Allowed Footprint=65571KB, Trimmed=0KB
07-25 17:17:49.152: E/MediaStore(3008): failed to allocate memory for thumbnail content://media/external/images/thumbnails/300; java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=65571KB, Allocated=63718KB)
07-25 17:17:49.302: E/dalvikvm-heap(3008): Out of memory on a 480016-byte allocation.
07-25 17:17:49.317: E/dalvikvm(3008): Out of memory: Heap Size=65571KB, Allocated=63749KB, Limit=65536KB
07-25 17:17:49.317: E/dalvikvm(3008): Extra info: Footprint=65315KB, Allowed Footprint=65571KB, Trimmed=0KB
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=65571KB, Allocated=63749KB)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:552)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at android.media.ThumbnailUtils.createThumbnailFromEXIF(ThumbnailUtils.java:515)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at android.media.ThumbnailUtils.createImageThumbnail(ThumbnailUtils.java:102)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at android.provider.MediaStore$InternalThumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:626)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Thumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:987)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.GalleryActivity.Gallery(GalleryActivity.java:92)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.GalleryActivity.access$1(GalleryActivity.java:74)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.GalleryActivity$LoadGallery.doInBackground(GalleryActivity.java:58)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.GalleryActivity$LoadGallery.doInBackground(GalleryActivity.java:1)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008):     ... 5 more
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008): Activity com.mimi.ngsbusproject.GalleryActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41ac90a8 that was originally added here
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mimi.ngsbusproject.GalleryActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41ac90a8 that was originally added here
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:465)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:419)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:351)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:171)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:558)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:282)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.GalleryActivity$LoadGallery.onPreExecute(GalleryActivity.java:51)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.GalleryActivity.onCreate(GalleryActivity.java:43)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-25 17:17:50.062: E/WindowManager(3008):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 17:17:50.962: E/dalvikvm-heap(3008): Out of memory on a 2264368-byte allocation.
07-25 17:17:50.967: E/dalvikvm(3008): Out of memory: Heap Size=65571KB, Allocated=63787KB, Limit=65536KB
07-25 17:17:50.967: E/dalvikvm(3008): Extra info: Footprint=65315KB, Allowed Footprint=65571KB, Trimmed=0KB
07-25 17:17:50.967: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3008): crash in the same process: main
07-25 17:17:50.967: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3008): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=65571KB, Allocated=63787KB)
07-25 17:17:50.967: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3008):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
07-25 17:17:50.967: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3008):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:626)
07-25 17:17:50.967: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3008):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
07-25 17:17:50.967: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3008):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:502)
07-25 17:17:50.967: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3008):     at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.LuancherActivity.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(LuancherActivity.java:147)
07-25 17:17:50.967: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3008):     at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.LuancherActivity.AnimateandSlideShow(LuancherActivity.java:113)
07-25 17:17:50.967: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3008):     at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.LuancherActivity.access$0(LuancherActivity.java:106)
07-25 17:17:50.967: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3008):     at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.LuancherActivity$2.run(LuancherActivity.java:84)
```

And My code here.

```
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    Cursor image_cursor;
    image_cursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
            null, null);
    int image_column_index = image_cursor
            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    count = image_cursor.getCount();
    thumbnails = new Bitmap[count];
    arrPath = new String[count];
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            image_cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int id = image_cursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = image_cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
            arrPath[i] = image_cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Sorry for my language. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Part:

```
count = image_cursor.getCount();
thumbnails = new Bitmap[count];
```

May cause this. For creating Bitmaps memory-efficient you should use BitmapOptions

Try **THIS** instead:

```
Bitmap bm;
bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath),100, 100, true);
mPicture = new ImageView(context);
mPicture.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

See
[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Seems like these both logs may give you the hint:

> failed to allocate memory for thumbnail
>   content://media/external/images/thumbnails/300;

.

> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
>   07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008): at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:552)
>   07-25 17:17:49.327: E/AndroidRuntime(3008): at
>   android.media.ThumbnailUtils.createThumbnailFromEXIF

Does your gallery contain a lot of big pictures?
In this case you dont have a problem with your `Cursor` but with your memory management when it comes to bitmaps!

Furthermore you should have this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

See also

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Hi Thomas, I'm facing the exact same problem as the OP's. I'm even loading the Micro Kind, and still I'm getting alot of reports indicating that there is an OutOfMemoryExcpetion in various devices. I didn't really understand what you suggest. I shouldn't keep a bitmap array to contain all the thumbnails and use it in my Image Adapter? Could you explain what is your solution please?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

As for the the out of memory i used to get this when i have very large images in size, try to
test it in small images ..

Comment: Thanks @user1283633 for your answer.But after I try to add your example code to my manifest file but it still doesn't work for me. :(

Answer (score 1):

my advice to all , try dont use large image size use https://tinypng.com/ to decrease the image size

Second increase heap size from mainfest `android:largeHeap="true"` in application tag to be like this

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true">
```

and bundle max heap size

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

   .......
   ....

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

    }
}
```

I hope this help

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

in your Manifest application tag.

Comment: Really not recommended in this kind of app, meant to use in very heavy app like PhotoEditor and so

Comment: This only delays the problem temporarily, and doesn't solve the root problem