# Fragments image fatal error on Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Why I'm getting this error ?? Anyone can help me ??

If need something more (the fail console is very big lol) I'm just trying to do a tutorial, with some images, that the user scroll from rigth to left, or click a next/back button and change the view for the next of the tutorial, and I don't know if I'm doing well:

I'm using one fragment per tutorial image, and when user click on next button the view changes to next image.

You can find the actual code here: https://github.com/j0sete/fragments.git

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 33177612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 31MB until OOM
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Bitmap you're trying to load are eating away the phone's memory. Take a look at these and see if it helps:

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

[Android - Out of memory Error. When it run on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855325/android-out-of-memory-error-when-it-run-on-real-device)